# What underlying semantic notions explain 'quotus' in 'quotidianus'?

Tags: etymology

> [ [Wiktionary :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotidian#Etymology) ]  [...]  Latin cottīdiānus, quōtīdiānus ‎(“happening every day”), from adverb cottīdiē, quōtīdiē ‎(“every day, daily”),
>   from an unattested adjective derived from [*quot*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quot#Latin) ‎(“how many”) + locative form of [*diēs*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#Latin) ‎(“day”).
>
> [ [Etymonline :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=quotidian) ]  [...]  from Latin *quotidianus* "daily," from Latin *quotus* "how many? which in order or number?" (see [quote](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quote&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)) + *dies* "day" (see [diurnal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=diurnal&allowed_in_frame=0)).  [...]

'quot' and 'quotus' appear a wrong, discordant choice  of adjective to Compound *dies*, because they are used to connect or question a quantity with another noun'; but the frequency and quantity in  'every day' is evident: it is 'every'. So an adjective like [omnis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omnis#Latin) appears more reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not 'every' day, but 'any' day. Think of it along the lines of 'how soever many days', i.e., all days.

See [Cicero's *Letters to Atticus* 5.7](https://archive.org/details/letterstoatticus01ciceuoft) (or on [Perseus](http://data.perseus.org/citations/urn:cts:latinLit:phi0474.phi057.perseus-lat1:5.7)) for a distinction between *cotidie* and *in dies singulos*. In the translation linked to above, we read:

> Daily, or rather more and more every day, I send you shorter letters...

for:

> cotidie vel potius in dies singulos breviores litteras ad te mitto...

This is a loose translation, but the distinction seems to be along the lines of:

> On whatsoever day [you might pick/name], or, rather, on every single day, I send you shorter letters...